# Can I purchase Mass Effect 2 DLC without "owning" the video game?

Tags: xbox-360, mass-effect-2

I rent games via GameFly and really want to play the DLC.  Do I need to own ME2 to purchase/play the DLC?

Comment: Hm. Mass Effect 2 is a special case, given the way the Cerberus Network works. If you already own a cerberus network key (which is sold separately), the point is moot. If you don't, then I'm not quite sure what happens...

Comment: You can buy access to the Cerberus Network as DLC for 1200 MS points.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need the game to purchase DLC, but you need it to play the downloaded content.

Comment: so I'd need to buy membership to the cerberus network AND buy the DLC too? I'd probably be better off just buying the game in that case then.

Comment: Far as I know, yes, you'd need both. But I hope somebody else can confirm just to be sure.

Comment: @Mikey B, bear in mind that the Cerberus Network itself contains some DLC all on it's own -- Squadmate Zaeed, the Firewalker mission pack, and probably something else I'm forgetting as well.

Comment: You don't need the Cerberus Network to buy/play any of the other paid DLC, only for the DLC that is free w/ the Cerberus Network. If you want everything, then you'd need to buy the Cerberus Network. I'm not sure if I'd go through all that for a rented game, but that's just me.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no. You can purchase some DLC by itself from the Xbox 360 Marketplace, a list of available content is linked [here](http://marketplace.xbox.com/en-US/games/media/66acd000-77fe-1000-9115-d802454108ce/?p=1&of=3&bt=0&sb=1#offers). Most of the important DLC is available in Marketplace.

ME2 also has the Cerberus Network which is a one time purchase for access to the content. Once you are a member, Cerberus Network content is available to you at no extra charge. A list of Cerberus content is [here](http://masseffect.bioware.com/info/cerberus/). If you are playing the game through GameFly, the Cerberus network is probably not worth it, however if you do own the game, the addition of Zaeed and the Firewalker pack is probably with it.

ME2 is a massive and rich game, you certaintly would benefit from some of the DLC, but it is not a must buy to get the whole story (with perhaps the exception of the Shadow Broker DLC)